# make model_averaging exclusive in federated learning using Python Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, mutex, condition-variable, federated-learning

I am creating `num_of_clients` threads using the following code:

```
sockets_thread = []
no_of_client = 1

all_data = b""
while True:
    try:
        for i in range(no_of_client):
            connection, client_info = soc.accept() 
            print("\nNew Connection from {client_info}.".format(client_info=client_info))
            socket_thread = SocketThread(connection=connection,
                                     client_info=client_info, 
                                     buffer_size=1024,
                                     recv_timeout=100)
            sockets_thread.append(socket_thread)
        for i in range(no_of_client):    
            sockets_thread[i].start()
            sockets_thread[i].join()
    except:
        soc.close()
        print("(Timeout) Socket Closed Because no Connections Received.\n")
        break
```

In the run function, there are several pieces of code, as follows:

```
class SocketThread(object):
     def run(self):
           while True: 
                received_data, status = self.recv()
                if status == 0:
                    self.connection.close() 
                    break
     
                self.reply(received_data)

     def reply(self, received_data):
        model = SimpleASR()
        #all threads must averge the model before going to next line
        model_instance = self.model_averaging(model, model_instance)
        print("All threads completed model averging.")
        #now do rest of the things
```

In the reply function, I have called one function. I want to write this code in such a way that every thread will proceed to the next line after calling this function.

Every thread must average the model and then proceed to the next line. I understood that I have to use Python condition variable. How can I do that?

The following functions must be mutually exclusive.

```
model_instance = self.model_averaging(model, model_instance)
```

Every thread will proceed to the next line after executing this piece of code.

I am writing this code as part of implementing a federated learning algorithm.
[image]

Comment: Python multi-threading doesn't run threads simultaneously because of the GIL.

Comment: If you need true concurrency you have to use multiprocessing.

Comment: I need this piece of code will be run by every thread and then will proceed to next line. Not required that this function will be run simultaneously. 

model_instance = self.model_averaging(model, model_instance)

Comment: The question is updated. I am writing this code as part of implementing a federated learning algorithm.

Comment: Please clarify your question. There appears to be a lot of code that's not relevant to your problem. Can you provide a simplified MRE that exposes the issue you're dealing with?

Comment: I require that all threads proceed to the next line after averaging the model. model_instance = self.model_averaging(model, model_instance)

Comment: Why do you think you need this lock step approach?  If more data is available for this thread, why should it not simply move on and handle that data?

Comment: As suggested by federated learning algorthm, model average by clients should be in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

`t.join()` probably does not do what you think it does:

```py
for i in range(no_of_client):    
    sockets_thread[i].start()
    sockets_thread[i].join()
```

When your main thread calls `sockets_thread[i].join()`, that call will not return until the thread in question has finished. Your loop only starts each next thread after the previous thread has completely finished whatever it was supposed to do.

If you want the threads to run concurrently, then don't `join` any of them until after you have `start`ed all of them:

```py
for i in range(no_of_client):    
    sockets_thread[i].start()
for i in range(no_of_client):    
    sockets_thread[i].join()
```

---

P.S., Some people might think it looked more pythonic if you wrote it like this:

```py
for t in sockets_thread:
    t.start()
for t in sockets_thread:
    t.join()
```

Probably more pythonic still if you used Python's [`map` function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/), but I'm not going there right now.